# How to get all products with pagination using REST API in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Is it possible to get all products with pagination using REST API in Magento 2?

I'm using REST API Get all product with pagination. E.g. in first page show 20 products, second page 20 products, etc...

Comment: @RAJDIP If you have a new question, you can ask a new question. Don't edit other questions to add more.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following search criteria:

```
/rest/all/V1/products?searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=20
```

Increase the currentPage until you get to the last page.

More details here: [Search using REST endpoints](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html)